# Why is pytest hook defined in the same file not running?

Tags: pytest

In the [py.test documentation (v3.0.3)](http://doc.pytest.org/en/3.0.3/example/simple.html#making-test-result-information-available-in-fixtures) it states that I can make a test hook like this:

```
import pytest


@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    print "Running hook!"

    yield

    print "Doing interesting stuff inside hook!"


def test_call_fails():
    assert False
```

But running it (`pytest -s mytest.py`), I don't get any printed output.

I believe this is because the hook is never run -- why is this?

Answer (score 4):

I figured out that I need to put the hook in a separate file `conftest.py` (in the same folder) in order for it to be run:

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest

@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    print "Running hook!"

    yield

    print "Doing interesting stuff inside hook!"
```

**mytest.py**

```
def test_call_fails():
    assert False
```

And now it works!

*this is also shown in the documentation with the comment `# contents of conftest.py` but this unfortunately wasn't clear to me at all in my numerous readthroughs :/*

Comment: Besides required to be in `conftest.py`, another fallacy is your test class inheriting from `unittest.TestCase`. If you do that, the tests run but the hooks won't fire. Took me half a day to figure out.